# Keycloak Forgot password duplicate emails

Tags: keycloak

Keycloak sends out duplicate emails when you hit Forgot password button right after user session expired and you want to login again.

It might be configuration issue with Keycloak but it is quite annoying so any help would be appreciated.

Keycloak client is set to public and used in combination javascript adapter on mobile app.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Login with your user account using public client.
2. Wait for your access token to expire and you will need to login again.
3. Go to login page and instead of login hit Forgot password button.
4. Enter your email and hit submit.
5. You get your first forgot password email.
6. You will be redirected to login-page-expired and on "click here" link.
7. You get your second password email (which shouldn't happen).

Used Keycloak version is 12.0.1.

Comment: which keycloak version are you using?

Comment: We are using Keycloak version 12.0.1. Also updated description to reflect that.